# jQuery click or mouseover function not getting hit

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML element:

```
<a href='#' class='receipt' id='{some id. generated dynamically}'>Receipt</a>
```

I have the following jQuery, to handle a click:

```
$('.receipt').click(function () {
                alert('hai');
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
            });
```

For some reason, when I click....nothing happens. I originally was trying to use `mouseover`, but I thought I was doing it incorrectly so I tried `click`. No dice..am I missing something here?

**UPDATE - This is how it ended up working, I'm using `.live` over `.on` as Jeff B suggested, but I'm sure `.on` would work just as well.**

```
$('.receipt').live('click', function () {
  alert('hai');
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**UPDATE 2 - `.on` will be replacing `.live` in the future, so you should probably use `.on`.**

Comment: Should be `$('.receipt').click(...`

Comment: It works for me in jsFiddle.  You must have some other code that manipulates that link.

Comment: That's already there...I just typed it in incorrectly. Why is this being downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention that the id is generated dynamically.  If the element is created after the handler is created, it will not work.

For dynamic elements, use `.on()`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.receipt', function() {
    alert('hai');
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

In this case, `body` is the element that essentially handles the click, once the event travels up the DOM, and then it makes sure it originated in `.receipt`.  Instead of `body`, you could use any element that is a parent/ancestor of the `.receipt` divs, preferably closer.

Because `body` handles the click, the handler is attached to something that always exists.  This way you can add and remove `.receipt` elements without worrying about the handler disappearing.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh....that's exactly it. I'm using `.live` instead of `.on` now - do you know if there is a difference? Thank you!

Comment: In practice, no, but in later versions of jQuery, `.live()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()` which replaces `live`, `delegate`, and `bind`.  See the first paragraph after the function description here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

Change `$('receipt')` to `$('.receipt')`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a '.' in your selector.  It is used to select classes.

It should be: `$('.receipt')`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `$('.receipt')` to access the div with it's css selector

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `.` character to use the class selector

```
$('.receipt').click(function () {
     alert('hai');
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

See the [class selector docs here](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

you must to remember that when you use class you must to write .className and if you are using id u must to use #idName for that reason u must to change $('receipt') to $('.receipt')